# PostgreSQL Recursive Query for function dependencies

Tags: postgresql, recursion, dependencies

I am trying to get all functions used by a function of given proc_name, let it be 'my_f', both directly and indirectly (i.e. those used by the functions directly called by 'my_f' and so on).

I wrote a function that finds the name of the functions directly invoked by 'my_f':

```
select proc_name from oe.function_invoked(from => 'my_f')
```

and I get all functions explicitly called by 'my_f' but I do not understand how to use 'WITH RECURSIVE' to go deeper and get all the function names I need ..

Any help greatly appreciated,

I've tried with

```
WITH RECURSIVE f (proc_name) AS (
    SELECT proc_name FROM oe.function_invoked('snapshot_concessioni_focus_00')
  UNION ALL
    SELECT proc_name FROM oe.function_invoked(proc_name)
)
SELECT proc_name FROM f;
```

but it does not work

Answer (score 0):

Thinking more about it ... here is my solution:

```
  WITH RECURSIVE fs_required AS (
            SELECT proc_name
              FROM oe.funzioni_richiamate_00('snapshot_concessioni_focus_00')
             UNION
            SELECT y.proc_name
              FROM  fs_required x
                  , oe.funzioni_richiamate_00(x.proc_name) y
   ) SELECT * FROM fs_required;
```